# Updating multiple records at the same time in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Trying to update more than 1 record using a form submission in MVC (bringing existing data into the View from the DB and allowing user to make changes).

In the View, I can return as many existing records as I need ready to be edited, without a problem:

```
@model IEnumerable<object>
@{
    List<Portal.Models.Primary_Client> PClient = Model.ToList()[0] as List<Portal.Models.Primary_Client>;
    List<Portal.Models.Primary_Dependent> PDependant = Model.ToList()[1] as List<Portal.Models.Primary_Dependent>;
    List<Portal.Models.Primary_AnnExp> PAnnExp = Model.ToList()[2] as List<Portal.Models.Primary_AnnExp>;
    List<Portal.Models.Primary_IncExp> PIncEx = Model.ToList()[3] as List<Portal.Models.Primary_IncExp>;
    List<Portal.Models.Primary_InvAssets> PInvAssets = Model.ToList()[4] as List<Portal.Models.Primary_InvAssets>;
    List<Portal.Models.Primary_Liabilities> PLiabilities = Model.ToList()[5] as List<Portal.Models.Primary_Liabilities>;
    List<Portal.Models.Primary_LifeAssets> PLAssets = Model.ToList()[6] as List<Portal.Models.Primary_LifeAssets>;

    ViewBag.Title = "Completed Form";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditPLA/" + newid, "Forms", FormMethod.Post))
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < PLAssets.Count; i++)
                    {

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => PLAssets[i].LifAsset_ID)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => PLAssets[i].PLForm_ID)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(Model => PLAssets[i].Client_ID_PriFK)
                        </div>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    @Html.Label("Asset Type")
                                    @Html.EditorFor(Model => PLAssets[i].PLAsset_Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    @Html.Label("Asset Amount")
                                    @Html.EditorFor(Model => PLAssets[i].PLAmount_Per_Annum, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    }

                    <div class="button" style="text-align:center;">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                    </div>
                }
```

However, my model does not populate properly when I submit the form as the field names are not passing as expected and do not match my model field names. I suspect this is because of how I create the fields using the loop.

My Editor field names look like this:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="CS___8__locals1_PLAssets_0__PLAmount_Per_Annum" name="CS$<>8__locals1.PLAssets[0].PLAmount_Per_Annum" type="text" value="3">
```

When I would have expected to see something more like this:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="PLAmount_Per_Annum" name="PLAmount_Per_Annum" type="text" value="3">
```

I believe this is made more difficult than usual because I have several Models being passed to my View through an Object, but I don't know how else to create these fields with the correct name.

FYI - My Controller looks like this:

```
     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditPLA(List<Primary_LifeAssets> Assets, int id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var i in Assets)
                {
                    var c = db1.Primary_LifeAssets.Where(a => a.LifAsset_ID.Equals(i.LifAsset_ID)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        c.PLForm_ID = i.PLForm_ID;
                        c.PLAmount_Per_Annum = i.PLAmount_Per_Annum;
                        c.PLAsset_Type = i.PLAsset_Type;
                    }
                }
                db1.Entry(Assets).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db1.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Updated.";
                return RedirectToAction("Existing/" + id, "Forms");
            }

            ViewBag.Message = "Save failed.";
            return RedirectToAction("Existing/" + id, "Forms");
        }
```

Comment: Do not use `IEnumerable<object>` as your model. Create a view model containing the collection properties you want - e.g. `public List<.Primay_LifeAssets> PLAssets { get set; }` etc, and populate it in the GET method and pass it to the view

Comment: Show your model class also.